# It maybe seem unnecessary, but I want to reopen a spezific program after it is closed by ahk

Tags: autohotkey

This is how far i got:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_exe zotero.exe
f7::
WinGetTitle, Title, A
WinClose, A
Sleep 1000
IfWinNotExist(zotero)
{
Run,  zotero.exe , , Min
}
Return
```

I am unsure about the if statement in an if statement. How can I make it work?

Comment: See [WinExist()](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IfWinExist.htm). WinGetTitle and IfWinNotExist are unnecessary. Try [WinWaitClose](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinWaitClose.htm) before the Run command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use:

```
Loop {
    Sleep, 1000 ; just 1 second delay between any check
    process, Exist, "Zotero.exe"
    if ErrorLevel
        Run,  zotero.exe , , Min
}
```